# Application that can detect GSM signal proximity

Tags: android, signal-processing

15 years ago, I ever installed an application on my Symbian cellphone. That application:

- can detect any GSM cellphone signals,
- will list all GSM signal (it written as id on this app like mac address) which is discoverable / in range with my phone.
- once I select one of them, I can get the proximity where is the selected signal transmitter (in this case, cellphone) might be.

Does this kind of application is still available today on Android?

Comment: Never heard of such an app to locate *cell phones* via their GSM signal. However, there are a lot of [apps dealing with cell signals](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_cellsignal) to e.g. locate cell *towers.* Maybe one of those covers your case as well, though I don't remember having seen that feature listed.

Comment: Android doesn't give this kind of access to the radios to apps... Take a look at OpenSignal or LTE Discovery, those are about as close as you will get.

Comment: "can detect any GSM cellphone signals" - as someone who has spent decades developing software for telephone exchanges, cell towers and handsets (not to mention satellites), I can tell you that only the cell tower can detect ‘phones GSM signals. ‘Phones cannot detect each other’s GSM signals. What would be the point? They *can* detect WiFi & BlueTooth, but not GSM signal; t least, not off the shelf consumer ‘phones. Governments might find a use for packing a call tower into a ‘phone, although I doubt that it could be done. I am certain that you misremember what your Symbian was detecting.